# SQLSyntaxErrorException in Java. Strange Problem

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

> SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '1 * FROM payments' at line 1

This is the error which I've got. I do not know what is wrong with my code. The other already answered questions doesn't contain answer for my question. Here is my code:

```
   public void getAuto() throws Exception {



        String q1 = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM payments";
        try {
            rs3=st.executeQuery(q1); //here is the error
            String ppmail = rs3.getString("mail");

            String q2 = "Delete from tabela where ppmail="+ppmail;
            st.execute(q2);
            getData(ppmail);

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
            auto.setText("End of records");
        }


        auto.setText("1000 realised");
        }
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support SELECT TOP 1. (That's MS SQL Server syntax.)

Comment: First problem you should solve is knowing which dbms you are using.  Since when `MySQL` has `TOP 1` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in mysql  you should use limit  1

```
 SELECT * FROM payment LIMIT 1
```

and baded on your comment you second  error is related to the missinhg quote around email

```
"Delete from tabela where ppmail='"+ppmail +"';";
```

Comment: SQL tables/resultsets are by definition **orderless**.. So using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is **meaningless**. Basically you are asking MySQL here: "give me one record from the table `payment` but i don't care which one".

Comment: now I am having "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com' at line 1" at the line:  st.execute(q2);